# Ng2 innerHTML How to allow style attribute?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to render a HTML in Angular 2 with [innerHTML]. However angular 2 removes the style attribute from html elements. How can I get the styles rendered?

### component.ts

```
...
content = "<table><tr><td style="width:30%">Hallo</td><td style="width:70%">Welt</td></tr></table>"
---
```

### component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Comment: Only style is under the styles property apply to the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can address them with <strike>`/deep/`</strike> `::ng-deep`

```
@Component({
  styles: [`
    // :host /deep/ td { // old
    :host ::ng-deep td {
      width: 30%;
    }`
})
```

You also could disable style encapsulation for the component

```
@Component({
  ...,
  viewEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
)}
```

but that might bring other disadvantages as styles bleeding in and even styles without `/deep/` bleeding out.

Comment: Does this work generically without defining width?

Comment: What do you mean with "without defining width"? That's normal CSS, it's just added `/deep/` to cross component boundaries like `>` for direct child. Dynamically added HTML is treated similar to HTML from a child component.